# ¿Cómo generar las serie 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5... hasta N numero en lenguaje c mediante while?

Tags: c, while

Tengo un programa que me genera una serie de numeros como la siguiente: 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5...n

Esta serie continua hasta el numero entero que ingreses al inicio del programa. El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
  int N, i rep;
  printf("Ingrese un numero entero para generarla serie: ");
  scanf("%d",&N);

  for(i=1; i<=N; i++) {
    for(rep=1; rep<=1; rep++) {
      printf("%d ", i);
    }
  }
}
```

Este es el resultado al ejecutarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora intento hacer lo mismo con while en ves de for para obtener el mismo resultado, pero no logro obtenerlo.

Comment: Cambiando el.for a un while i <n y dentro de esas llaves i++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no sé si lo quieres con un `while` o con  dos. Si quieres conseguir el mismo bucle anidado, pues diría que, y eso te comenta el JackNavaRow, las declaraciones en el `for (/*declaraciones*/)` quedan afuera, entre las llaves `{`, `}` del bloque del bucle. Solo se queda la condición en el `while (/*conidción*/)`. ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
    int N = 5;
    int i = 0, rep = 1;
    while (++i <= N) {
        rep = 1;
        while (rep++ <= i)
            printf("%d ", i);
    }
}
```

los `++i` y `rep++` consiguen unir dos declaraciones entre los tres del `for (/*declaraciones*/)` a la condición del `while (/*condición*/)`, mientras los `i = 1` y `rep = 1` quedan afuera.

no sé si me explico

-- Dani